# How to send sms from Android NDK or Cocos2dx

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I want to send sms from cocos2d-x engine.If this engine can't send sms, does Android NDK support it? Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: using jni to wrap whatever fucntions in android sdk will be the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any native C functionality for sending SMS messages, but you can always use JNI to access [SMSManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html).